# Mail Sending to multiple recipient without sharing the email id using php

Tags: php

I have a send button who's id is 'btnEmail'.My code is sending mail to only the specified email.I want to send it to multiple people without sharing the email id.My code goes here:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnEmail']))
{
       require_once("../include/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
       $mail1 = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
       $mail1->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
       $mail1->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
       $mail1->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
       $mail1->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
       $mail1->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
       $mail1->Port = 465; // or 587
       $mail1->IsHTML(true);
       $mail1->Username = "some_mail@gmail.com";  // SMTP username
       $mail1->Password = "Sup3rS3cr3T"; // SMTP password
       $mail1->SetFrom("some_mail@gmail.com");
       $mail1->Subject = "Testing mail for php";
       $mail1->Body = "<html><h4>Tested Successfully</h4></html>";
       $mail1->AddAddress('another_mail@gmail.com');        
}
```

Comment: Then turn that code into a function with a parameter of ToAddress, then call it as many times as you want to send each email individually.

Comment: Please, don't post sensitive information, you MUST change your password account right now!

Comment: You will probably need this link to recover your Gmail: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/50270?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using phpmailer. Have you checked the examples it gives?

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps

This should be present on your computer or server. You can also read the documentation, it is helpful.